# Module store resetting to state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to figure out how resetting works with VueX store when the state is modularized.
This is my VueX structure:

```
└── store
    ├── index.js              
    └── module-cart
         ├── index.js         
         ├── actions.js       
         ├── mutations.js
         ├── state.js         
         ├── getters.js
```

So I want to reset the state to original state for this current module.

I created following mutation in `module-cart/mutations.js` file:

```
import initialState from './state.js';
export default {
  resetState(state) {
    Object.assign(state, initialState);
}
}
```

So I imported state from state.js file for this module as initialState and im trying to set it back to initial in my component.

The thing is it is not setting back to the initial one, the state is unchanged when the mutation is fired.

Here is my `module-cart/state.js` file:

```
export default function () {
  return {
    fileName: "",
    sheetName: "",
  }
}
```

And `module-cart/index.js`:

```
import state from './state'
import getters from './getters'
import mutations from './mutations'
import actions from './actions'


export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters
}
```

I think Im missing something but not sure what. How can I set initial state and working state in this kind of VueX structure for this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are exporting a function from `module-cart/state.js`. You should call it to get the default object.

```
import initialState from './state.js';
export default {
  resetState(state) {
    Object.assign(state, initialState());
 }
}
```

Notice me calling `initialState`.